# Using ffmpeg on Raspberry Pi to grab video from RTSP: "-t command not found"

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, command-line-arguments

I am trying something that should be simple - trying to use the Raspberry Pi ffmpeg to grab a 30 second video from an RTSP stream. The command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <rtsp:...> -t 30 <output>
```

The RTSP string gets long (70 to 80 characters or so). It always fails with:

```
[1] 5436
bash: -t command not found
```

Is this an ffmpeg problem or a Raspberry Pi configuration problem?

I have tried to research argument length limits, but came up empty.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Check out https://superuser.com/help/formatting for some tips on formatting your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an `&` character in the stream URL. On the command line you need to escape it with a `\`, since it's a special character in bash and will separate commands:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://host/path?param1=\&param2= -t 30
```

Note the `\&`. If not an ampersand, some other special character.

Or just put the URL in double quotes and be done with it:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://host/path?param1=&param2=" -t 30
```

---

The reason you get this error:

> ```
> bash: -t command not found
> ```

Is because, assuming there's an ampersand in your URL somewhere, bash (essentially) tries to execute two commands. So if you have (I'm making a reasonable guess at your URL):

> ```
> ffmpeg -i rtsp://example.com?x=0&y=0 -t 30
> ```

Bash tries to run:

1. ```
    ffmpeg -i rtsp://example.com?x=0
   ```
2. ```
    y=0 -t 30
   ```

Where the second one is parsed as "set environment variable `y` to `0` then execute the command `-t` with one parameter, `30`", and `-t` isn't an actual command. Hence, the error.

Your situation might not be exactly that, since I'm guessing, but that's the general idea.

Details of bash's behavior are outside the scope of this answer and have been generally skipped for brevity.

---

> Is this an ffmpeg problem or a Raspberry Pi configuration problem?
>
> I have tried to research argument length limits, but came up empty.

Btw, argument length limits are a non-issue here. :) It is [very large](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument). It's also hard-coded into the kernel, so there's no user configuration options for it.

Comment: You are correct - there are a couple of '&' in the RTSP string. I can only test it at the end of the day, but have no doubt that it will work now. Thanks for your thorough explanation!

Comment: Jason C, your answer is incredible: to the point and comprehensive.